# Frame around TikZ circle filled with image

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circles, border

I would like to draw a frame around a TikZ circle that is filled with a picture. Importantly, the code should follow the MWE below (if possible), since it is copied from a larger class definition, and I will probably not be able to integrate a different solution into the original code without running into new problems.

Here goes the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tikz\path[fill overzoom image={some_picture}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];

\end{document}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How precisely should the frame look like? As far as I can see, your code already clips the image. What would you like to add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

If you have a few of these then it is a good idea to wrap the code in a macro, as this ensures both uniformity and improves readability. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{mwe}% for an example image

\newcommand\CircledImage[1]{%
\tikz\path[fill overzoom image={#1}, draw=blue, line width=2mm]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];%
}
\begin{document}

\CircledImage{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for! Many thanks!